# Citrix Xen Live Migration without a pool

Tags: xenserver, citrix, migration

I have Citrix XenServer 6.2
Is it possible to use the `xe vm-migrate` command without having a pool?

My command:

> xe vm-migrate vm=movetest host=newhost --live --force
>
> Error: Host newhost not found

Comment: Tried with IP and Hostname for remote-master, took attention to correct spelling and correct copied uuid. Still got Error: No matching VMs found. but I found a [script](http://djlab.com/2013/01/migrate-a-xenserver-vm-without-a-pool-or-shared-storage/#comment-814) that did the trick:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
host= should be used when migrating to another host in the pool.
When migrating outside the pool(no pool) you should use these options:
remote-username=
remote-master=
remote-password=
```

Comment: Yes, that works. `xe vm-migrate remote-master=xxx remote-username=xxx remote-password=xxx vm=xxx live=true force=true` Thank you :)

Comment: That does not seem to work unless you are in the same pool?
Whatever I try, I always get a "could not find vm". Tried with vm or uuid, both fail.

Comment: That's strange.. It worked for me. Are you using a dns name or the ip address for `remote-master`? Please try both. And also check the correct spelling of your vm (don't know if case sensitive).